# How to exclude files from a webpack entry point

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass

I am using the following webpack config to handle / load all of my sass files. One important item is that I am using `additionalData` to preappend my common styles. This is causing a conflict, however, because my entry for webpack is any and all sass files, which means that my `commonStyles.scss` is already getting loaded. When I run my app, I get the following error:

**errorMessage:**

```
SassError: This file is already being loaded.
  ╷
1 │ @import "src/styles/commonStyles.scss";
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src/styles/sizes.scss 1:9  root stylesheet
```

How can I create an entry point that includes *all* sass files in my app *except for / excluding* `commonStyles.scss` (or better yet, any files in the `/src/styles/` folder)? Thanks for the help!

**webpack config:**

```js
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const glob = require('glob');
const path = require('path');

const sassRegex = /\.(scss|sass)$/;

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  bail: true,
  devtool: false,
  entry: glob.sync(`${path.resolve(fs.realpathSync(process.cwd()), 'src')}/**/*.{css,scss}`),
  output: {
    path: 'build',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: sassRegex,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              additionalData: `@import "src/styles/commonStyles.scss";`,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: Please reasearch more about Webpack conditions. Try here, I hope it helps: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of
`/**/*.{css,scss}` try `/**/!{commonStyles}.{css,scss}`

Alternatively:

```
entry: glob.sync(
  `${path.resolve(fs.realpathSync(process.cwd()), 'src')}/**/*.{css,scss}`,
  ignore: [
    '**/src/styles/commonStyles.scss',
  ],
),
```